# How can I remove the extra space on right side of my website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I have build a landing page using tailwindcss and glider.js for simple slider but after I finished the website I was struck with issue on responsive design part were I was sure that problem didn't occur when before and that is I have an extra space to right all most in all devices when I use chrome inspector device toolbar only on chrome works proberly on mozilla but only this website has this issue on chrome.

[image]

I have checked for any elements that may be the cause but without any luck.
as you can see my html element width is 1536 just like in dimension but the extra white space is accually more then 1536.

Answer (score 0):

The div class 2xl:max-w-[1535px] is probably causing the content not to stretch any further. Try changing this value in the css file and see if that helps.

In your main.css file:

```
    @media (min-width: 1536px) {

  .container {
    max-width: 1536px;
  }
}
```

In your index.html try to comment out the "container" class of the second div element in the body to see if this is causing the width limitation.

Comment: is not the issue here because at screen width of 2000px or more the problem persist.
I'm gonna chare a github link for this project soon

Comment: just to check I did as you said and removed this media query and max-width but with no luck at all.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that I was using transform translate for animations I have set overflow-hidden to body but didn't work.

The way I solve it was just apply `overflow:hidden` for the parent of all elements with animations.